# Robot Framework + Sauce labs can't recognize the Browser Edge name

Tags: robotframework, saucelabs

i am running my robot framework test in Sauce labs, for chrome/firefox/safari, it is all right. but for Edge, Sauce labs can't recognize the Edge browser name.

I try to use "edge", it complain. "Misconfigured -- Unsupported OS/browser/version/device combo: OS: 'Windows 10', Browser: 'edge', Version: '97.', Device: 'unspecified' "

I try to use "MicrosoftEdge", it complains "ValueError: microsoftedge is not a supported browser."

what is the correct Edge name for Robot framework+sauce lab?  my test case like the followings, Any suggestion is welcomed.  Thanks.

```
test
   &{SAUCE_OPTIONS}    Create Dictionary    extendedDebugging=${True}
    ...    capturePerformance=${True}
    ...    seleniumVersion=4.0.0
    ...    name=RF_Test
    ...    build='demo'
    &{DESIRED_CAPABILITIES}    Create Dictionary
    ...    browserName=MicrosoftEdge
    ...    platform=Windows 10
    ...    browserVersion=latest
    ...    sauce:options=&{SAUCE_OPTIONS}
    ${remote_url}    Set Variable    https://sauceUserName:sauce_a...@ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub
    Open Browser    https://google.com
    ...    browser=${DESIRED_CAPABILITIES['browserName']}
    ...    remote_url=${remote_url}
    ...    desired_capabilities=${desired_capabilities}
    # ...    options=${options}
    Sleep    5s
    Close Browser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the Robot Framework issue or the Sauce labs issue. but I can do some trick to make the Edge work with RF+Sauce labs.
the problem is happening at browser parameter in the Keyword  Open Browser.  if just keep this browser as default firefox, and specify "MicrosoftEdge" in the desired capabilities for sauce labs.  the test will run as expected.
The only bad thing for this trick is when you read RF log file, it said *"Opening browser 'firefox' to base url 'https://XX.com' through remote server at...,*
Actually, it is opening Edge browser.

```
test
   &{SAUCE_OPTIONS}    Create Dictionary    
    ...    name=RF_Test
    ...    build='demo'
    &{DESIRED_CAPABILITIES}    Create Dictionary
    ...    browserName=MicrosoftEdge
    ...    platform=Windows 10
    ...    browserVersion=latest
    ...    sauce:options=&{SAUCE_OPTIONS}
    ${remote_url}    Set Variable    https://sauceUserName:sauce_a...@ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub
    Open Browser    https://google.com
    ***#...    browser=${DESIRED_CAPABILITIES['browserName']}#get rid of this parameter#***
    ...    remote_url=${remote_url}
    ...    desired_capabilities=${desired_capabilities}
    Sleep    5s
    Close Browser
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't well documented, and when used locally, it will work with several values, but the one it identifies itself as is `msedge`

```
2022-02-21 12:44:53 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:9515/session | {"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"browserName":"MicrosoftEdge","unhandledPromptBehavior":"ignore","ms:edgeOptions":{}}}}

2022-02-21 12:45:00 INFO Selenium <- {"value":{"capabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserName":"msedge","browserVersion":"98.0.1108.51","ms:edgeOptions":{"debuggerAddress":"localhost:52338"},"msedge":{"msedgedriverVersion":"98.0.1108.56 (9a336a18eae89157b3c7ea0568a9cbced8ebc3f7)","userDataDir":"/var/folders/fx/nlx77ccs72g808pr1994_xtw0000gn/T/.com.microsoft.edgemac.5dBA6q"},"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"mac os x","proxy":{},"setWindowRect":true,"strictFileInteractability":false,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000},"unhandledPromptBehavior":"ignore","webauthn:extension:credBlob":true,"webauthn:extension:largeBlob":true,"webauthn:virtualAuthenticators":true},"sessionId":"103b9fc98e46a159a3d91effe98e5d33"}}
```

For Sauce Labs, though, please use the platform configurator to see exactly what you should be sending to Sauce Labs — https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator

The code is updated to use Selenium libraries not Robot, so if you are creating it from scratch, you can see what is expected from the node.js + w3c tabs.

Your specific code is not working because you need to use `platformName` instead of `platform`.

Comment: hmm,  even I use platformName, it still can't recognize Edge. same error. so confused.

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for **Edge**, you did not mention if you tried that one.

Documentation is not clear about examples for [browserName](https://docs.saucelabs.com/dev/test-configuration-options/#browsername).
Also reading [WebDriver W3C Specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-browser-name) does give an answer.

Comment: Thanks.  But i tried to use 'Edge' in my code, same issue for  complain "WebDriverException: Message: Misconfigured -- Unsupported OS/browser/version/device combo: OS: 'Windows 10', Browser: 'edge', Version: 'latest', Device: 'unspecified'"

Comment: You still show lowercase Edge. Try Pascal case, Edge.

Comment: that is weird. i use "Edge" in my code. but i don't know why it complain 'edge'. 
 this is my log file,KEYWORD &{DESIRED_CAPABILITIES} = BuiltIn . Create Dictionary browserName=Edge, platformName=Windows 10, browserVersion=90, sauce:options=&{SAUCE_OPTIONS}
Documentation: 
Creates and returns a dictionary based on the given items.
Start / End / Elapsed: 20220221 14:43:07.925 / 20220221 14:43:07.926 / 00:00:00.001
14:43:07.926 INFO &{DESIRED_CAPABILITIES} = { browserName=Edge | platformName=Windows 10 | browserVersion=90 | sauce:options={'name': 'RF_Test', 'build': "'demo'"} }

Comment: OK. Maybe you need to use only the minimal mandatory options. For example, the browserVersion you are requesting may be the one missing and thus fails the configuration.

Comment: Sauce Labs requires `browserName` of `MicrosoftEdge` and `browserVersion` of `latest` is valid.

Comment: it failed due to "ValueError: 'microsoftedge' is not a supported browser."  and the test didn't trigger any sauce labs action.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace? Perhaps Robot is interfering somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As browserName in desired capabilities use 'MicrosoftEdge'
But with 'Open Browser' keyword you should use 'edge' as browser
This solution works for me